# offset issue in one partition kafka storm consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

There is a topology that that read data from kafka and process.
When I am checking lag from kafka tool, I can see issue in offset update for one partition out of 6 partitions.
Even I see topology is processing latest messages from that partition also.
looks like offset stored in Storm for Storm consumer is corrupt.

[image]

Comment: Look at the consumer logs. Maybe there is a poison pill record in that partition

Comment: I re-deploy the topology...but still issue is not resolved and again same partition-3 showing lag, however other are fine. Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Like I said, a specific message may be stopping that partition from progressing, and your logs should be able to tell you why